# I uninstalled all graphic drivers and reinstalled but can't use my graphic card

Tags: ubuntu

`Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:9bc4  Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] vendor: Dell driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f12  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: nvidia compositor: gnome-shell resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz, 3840x2160~60Hz  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes` [image]

This is what I've tried after I reinstalled the driver.
Please give me the answer

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.   If you need to copy and paste from a console, install the `gpm` package.

Comment: Tell us why you uninstalled the graphics drivers; also what model etc of nvidia card do you have? Say what OS you are using [probably Ubuntu?]. Run `inxi -Gxx` and copy the output. Then edit your question with all this information.

Comment: @JeremyBoden  I edited my post. I got a problem that I can't boot my Ubuntu 20.04. so I changed Prime to intel and then ubuntu couldn't detect nvidia anymore.